# Why are the strings in my iterator being concatenated?

Tags: iterator, rust, type-inference

My original goal is to fetch a list of words, one on each line, and to put them in a `HashSet`, while discarding comment lines and raising I/O errors properly. Given the file "stopwords.txt":

```
a
# this is actually a comment
of
the
this
```

I managed to make the code compile like this:

```
fn stopword_set() -> io::Result<HashSet<String>> {
    let words = Result::from_iter(
        BufReader::new(File::open("stopwords.txt")?)
                .lines()
                .filter(|r| match r {
                    &Ok(ref l) => !l.starts_with('#'),
                    _ => true
                }));
    Ok(HashSet::from_iter(words))
}

fn main() {
    let set = stopword_set().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", set);
    assert_eq!(set.len(), 4);
}
```

Here's a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=41b23fab7d3336f239862d33aefbffb1&version=stable&backtrace=0) that also creates the file above.

I would expect to have a set of 4 strings at the end of the program. To my surprise, the function actually returns a set containing a single string with all words concatenated:

```
{"aofthethis"}
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left == right)` (left: `1`, right: `4`)'
```

Led by a piece of advice in the docs for [`FromIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html), I got rid of all calls to `from_iter` and used `collect` instead ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b00e617dd0c52832af99f6967cd0835b&version=stable&backtrace=0)), which has indeed solved the problem.

```
fn stopword_set() -> io::Result<HashSet<String>> {
    BufReader::new(File::open("stopwords.txt")?)
            .lines()
            .filter(|r| match r {
                &Ok(ref l) => !l.starts_with('#'),
                _ => true
            }).collect()
}
```

Why are the previous calls to `from_iter` leading to unexpected inferences, while `collect()` works just as intended?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simpler reproduction:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::iter::FromIterator;

fn stopword_set() -> Result<HashSet<String>, u8> {
    let input: Vec<Result<_, u8>> = vec![Ok("foo".to_string()), Ok("bar".to_string())];
    let words = Result::from_iter(input.into_iter());
    Ok(HashSet::from_iter(words))
}

fn main() {
    let set = stopword_set().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", set);
    assert_eq!(set.len(), 2);
}
```

The problem is that here, we are collecting from the iterator twice. The type of `words` is `Result<_, u8>`. However, `Result` *also* implements `Iterator` itself, so when we call `from_iter` on that at the end, the compiler sees that the `Ok` type must be `String` due to the method signature. Working backwards, you can construct a `String` from an iterator of `Strings`, so that's what the compiler picks.

Removing the second `from_iter` would solve it:

```
fn stopword_set() -> Result<HashSet<String>, u8> {
    let input: Vec<Result<_, u8>> = vec![Ok("foo".to_string()), Ok("bar".to_string())];
    Result::from_iter(input.into_iter())
}
```

Or for your original:

```
fn stopword_set() -> io::Result<HashSet<String>> {
    Result::from_iter(
        BufReader::new(File::open("stopwords.txt")?)
                .lines()
                .filter(|r| match r {
                    &Ok(ref l) => !l.starts_with('#'),
                    _ => true
                }))
}
```

---

Of course, I'd normally recommend using `collect` instead, as I prefer the chaining:

```
fn stopword_set() -> io::Result<HashSet<String>> {
    BufReader::new(File::open("stopwords.txt")?)
        .lines()
        .filter(|r| match r {
            &Ok(ref l) => !l.starts_with('#'),
            _ => true,
        })
        .collect()
}
```

Comment: Damn, got about 2/3rd of the way through writing mine up.

Comment: @DK. maybe you've got a better / different / more understandable explanation?

Comment: Nah, it was more or less the same thing, written in reverse order.